# Contact Data Portability Report has wrong data

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, analytics

I ran Contact Data Portability Report for a subscriber. I have few questions on the results:

[image]

1. Can a unique Subscriber Key have multiple Subscriber IDs?
2. This email was never bounced, still it has 'DateBounced2' field populated. Also, in NumberOfBounces2,
   it shows a date format while in 'DateJoined2' it shows a number value.

Does this report not show accurate results or am I not understanding this correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Subscriberkey can be duplicated if it exists in the all subs and the triggeredsend manager list

Comment: @EazyE can you point me to documentation related the triggeredsend manager list ?

Comment: In the documentation there's not really something useful, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_contact_data_portability.htm&type=5 , have you tried to create a case with support?

Comment: Will both the contacts be tied to one contact? @EazyE